# SQL Server not all statements in Batch are executed

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm using Microsoft's SQL Server 2008 R2 (the choice of server version is dictated by the customer).

Note, before each and every test I run this:

```
UPDATE apps set AssetId = NULL;
```

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I run the following queries:

```
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=2;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=3;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=4;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=5;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=6;
UPDATE apps set AssetId=1 WHERE id=7;
```

... the query runs without error, and as expected the following returns 7:

```
select count(*) from apps where AssetId=1;
```

So far so good.

Now I set all AssetIds to NULL, then run the same queries from a VB6 binary. I store all 7 queries in a single string variable and execute them using a ADO Recordset object. I check the SQL profiler and observe that all the queries appear within a SQL:BatchStarting EventClass. There are no errors (I selected to display all errors and warnings when setting up the profiler). Yet this returns 4:

```
select count(*) from apps where AssetId = 1;

-- Only 4 records have an AssetId which is not null:
select id, AssetId from apps where AssetId = 1;
select id, AssetId from apps where AssetId is not null;
```

I rearranged the UPDATE statements, set AssetId to null for all rows again, then ran the update statements. Still only 4 rows get updated (the rows corresponding to the first 4 update statements in the batch).

Why would only the first 4 statements in a batch of 7 be run? Why would ADO Recordset and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio have different results for the exact same queries when using the same database on the same server instance?

It almost seems that ADO Recordset has a maximum number of update statements it can run in a single batch (even though the profiler sees all 7 in the batch).

[Further Information added]
I've changed the profiler field outputs, and using the same queries I see a different behavior now. As before only 4 rows update, however, in the profiler the the SQL:BatchingStarting shows all 7 semi-colon separated fields, but only 4 of the 7 statements have a SQL:StmtStarting" EventClass record (3 of the queries are not mentioned at all by the profiler). As before I have all errors/warning checked. I'm fairly sure that before I was see one one SQL:StmtStarting for each query in the batch.

Comment: what happens when you change it to `up date apps set assetid=1 where id  >= and id<8`? and you said you see each statement executing in profiler?

Comment: Yes, I see the single batch with 7 statements. Then I see the profiler log message for each individual statement. If I execute just the last 4 update statements they update correctly. It's so strange. It seems to have something to do with having multiple update statements in the same batch which update the same table (except different rows). The odd thing is that I do the same logic in other places in my binary where each batch is 500 queries and it runs without problem. As for your statement, the issue is that the queries are auto-generated by something I don't control.

Comment: I think I *may* have figured out the issue. When I altered the logging I now see a message. It's EventClass is "Deprecation Announcement" and its TextData is, "The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it.". This message is repeated 6 times for each update statement. Maybe when X many of these messages are accumulated the SQL engine stops executing statements in the batch?

Comment: Well, to me it doesn't sound like a SQL Server limitation or issue, but rather VB6 issue, no?

Comment: No, because VB6 is giving to the database the exact same batch as is SQL Management studio. This I observe by using the SQL profiler.

Comment: But you can run it in ssms...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144695/discussion-between-scsimon-and-developer-webs).

Comment: @scsimon Yes. See the solution I provided. It works every time for me, and is reproducible every time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to disable the advanced option named "disallow results from triggers". When this option is enabled, even if your triggers don't return record sets, it causes the batch to not execute all statements and seems to give no error or warning.

I ran this:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO

EXEC sp_configure 'disallow results from triggers', '1';
RECONFIGURE;
```

... with this done all UPDATE statements in my transaction now complete.

I think perhaps with 'show advanced options' set to 0 (the default for SQL Server 2008) the batch was accumulating warning messages:

> The ability to return results from triggers will be removed in a
>   future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   it.

I suspect that after X many of these are accumulated the server stops executing statements within the Batch, no error is given, and the Batch is marked as completed.